# Get swf parameters in action script 2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, url-parameters

How can I get swf parameters using actionscript2? like

```
myflash.swf?p=1
```

or

```
<param name="flashvars" value="p=1" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly:

`<param name="FlashVars" value="example=test">` under the other param tags, and
`flashvars="example=test"` as extra attribute in the embed tag.

The variable will then be globally accessible in the movie.

`trace(example)`
-> output: test

Answer (score 0):

```
<embed src="myApplication.swf?name1=value1&name2=value2" />

var s:String = stage.loaderInfo.parameters["name2"];
```

Comment: This is for ActionScript 3, while the question was for AS2.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have the answer to this. Create an intermediate webpage with the parameters you need and get the xml or html. You could write a file with an url and return the url with loadVars. But it needs sinchronization. There should be easier like url parameters or javascript.